# Table column width gets changed after rendering second time - JQuery DataTables

Tags: html, jquery, css, ajax, datatables

JQuery DataTables cells width is extended after adding hyperlink to cell. Is there a way to avoid this?

There are two tables on the same page. First table column has a link which populates second table.
It works when the first time table is rendered but on the second time the column width is not same.

**When table is rendered the first time**

[image]

**Calling same method to render the same table again**

[image]

```
    var tblJanusPlate = $('#tbl').DataTable({
                
                "processing": true,
                //"serverSide": true,
                "bPaginate": false,
                "bFilter": false,
                "bInfo": false,
                "scrollY": "300px",
                "scrollCollapse": true,
                "bDestroy": true,
                "columns": [{
                    "data": "Name",
                    "width": "10%"
                },

                   {
                       "data": "Country",
                       "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {                          
                          return "<a href='" + data + "' id= '" + row + "' style='color: black; text-decoration: none;' onclick='return populateDetails(this,\"" + row.Name + "\",\"region\",\"" + regDate + "\");' >" + row.Record_Count + "</a>";
                   
                       }, "width": "10%"
                   }
                ]

            });
```

```
       $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Service.asmx/PlateStats",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                data: "{ regDate: '" + regDate + "', type: '" + command + "'}",
                success: function (response) {

                    response = JSON.parse(response);

                    tblJanusPlate.clear();
                    tblJanusPlate.rows.add(response[0]).draw(); 

                  
                }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is to do with "bDestroy" property. I could be wrong here but please feel free to comment.

After removing the destroy option, i tried this (from Datatable manual) and it worked for me.

[image]